# Any less ugly way to calculate object current coords in 2D when start pt, end pt, speed and movement start time are given?

Tags: c#, geometry, linear-algebra

Sorry, but geometry never was my favorite subject in school, so...

Currently I coding 2D MMORPG server emulator and want to improve my current coords detection algorithm.

Client send to server packets with `start point coords` and `finish point coords`.
Server receive it and assign `movement start` variable to `DateTime.Now`.
Server know what distance character can travel for 1 second (that's `speed`).
How to calculate character position after `some` seconds since he started movement?

Since I am bad at geometry, I coded this... junk... based on percents of traveled distance.
It's working through, but too much calculations.

```
        public ushort X;
        public ushort Y;
        public ushort TargetX;
        public ushort TargetY;

        public DateTime MovementStartTime;
        public ushort CalculatedX
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.X == this.TargetX && this.Y == this.TargetY)
                    return this.X;

                float total_dst = CF.GetEuclideanDistanceBetween(this.X, this.Y, this.TargetX, this.TargetY);
                float seconds_since_movement_start = (float)(DateTime.Now - this.MovementStartTime).TotalSeconds;
                float passed_dst = Limits.CharacterSpeed * seconds_since_movement_start;

                if (passed_dst > total_dst)
                    return this.TargetX;

                float passed_dst_in_normalized_percents = (passed_dst * 100 / total_dst) / 100;

                return (ushort)(this.X - ((this.X - this.TargetX) * passed_dst_in_normalized_percents));
            }
        }

        public ushort CalculatedY
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.X == this.TargetX && this.Y == this.TargetY)
                    return this.Y;

                float total_dst = CF.GetEuclideanDistanceBetween(this.X, this.Y, this.TargetX, this.TargetY);
                float seconds_since_movement_start = (float)(DateTime.Now - this.MovementStartTime).TotalSeconds;
                float passed_dst = Limits.CharacterSpeed * seconds_since_movement_start;

                if (passed_dst > total_dst)
                    return this.TargetY;

                float passed_dst_in_normalized_percents = (passed_dst * 100 / total_dst) / 100;

                return (ushort)(this.Y - ((this.Y - this.TargetY) * passed_dst_in_normalized_percents));
            }
        }
```

The idea is to determine how much percents of the line character already passed based on it's speed and then combine it with the flat distance between `start X` and `end X`.

Maybe someone know a less ugly way to do it?..
[image]

Comment: Some vector classes might make this easier.

Comment: What version of .net are you using?  the are some vector classes built into later versions.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Thank you for your answer. I use .net 4.0.

Comment: Me too, that's why I need my own vector classes.  .Net doesn't get them until 4.6 I think.

Comment: "Client send to server packets with start point coords and finish point coords." - Never forget that the client is in the hands of the enemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments a simple vector class will vastly simplify this.  If you are using a later version of .Net then you can use the Vector2 class in System.Numerics.  If you do not then you can just add my simple vector class (Vec2d) which I have included at the end of this post.

Then you can rewrite your two properties as a single property like this:

```
Vec2d calculatedXY
{
    get
    {
        Vec2d source = new Vec2d((float)this.X, (float)this.Y);
        Vec2d target = new Vec2d((float)this.TargetX, (float)this.TargetY);

        Vec2d diff = target - source;

        if(source == target)
            return source;

        float total_dst = diff.length;
        float seconds_since_movement_start = (float)(DateTime.Now - this.MovementStartTime).TotalSeconds;
        float passed_dst = Limits.CharacterSpeed * seconds_since_movement_start;

        if(passed_dst > total_dst)
            return target;

        return source + ((diff/total_dst) * passed_dst);
    }
}
```

Here's the Vec2d struct (could also be written as a class) if you need it:

```
public struct Vec2d
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;

    public Vec2d(float x_, float y_)
    {
        X = x_;
        Y = y_;
    }

    // calculated properties:
    public float length
    {
        get { return (float)Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y); }
    }


    // class operator definitions:

    // equality
    public static bool operator ==(Vec2d left, Vec2d right)
    {
        return (left.X == right.X) && (left.Y == right.Y);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Vec2d left, Vec2d right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    // addition
    public static Vec2d operator +(Vec2d left, Vec2d right)
    {
        return new Vec2d(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y);
    }
    // subtraction
    public static Vec2d operator -(Vec2d left, Vec2d right)
    {
        return new Vec2d(left.X - right.X, left.Y - right.Y);
    }

    // unary negation
    public static Vec2d operator -(Vec2d value)
    {
        return new Vec2d(-value.X, -value.Y);
    }

    // scalar multiplication
    public static Vec2d operator *(float scalar, Vec2d value)
    {
        return new Vec2d(scalar * value.X, scalar * value.Y);
    }
    public static Vec2d operator *(Vec2d value, float scalar)
    {
        return new Vec2d(scalar * value.X, scalar * value.Y);
    }

    // multiplication (vector dot product, NOT scalar dot product)
    public static Vec2d operator *(Vec2d left, Vec2d right)
    {
        return new Vec2d(left.X * right.X, left.Y * right.Y);
    }

    // scalar division
    public static Vec2d operator /(Vec2d value, float scalar)
    {
        return new Vec2d(value.X / scalar, value.Y / scalar);
    }
}
```

Comment: (Note: just fixed a couple of typos)

Answer (score 2):

When object is moving with constant speed, dependence of X-coordinate against time is

```
X = X0 + Vx * t
```

where `Vx` is x-component of velocity:

```
Vx = CharacterSpeed * dx / sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

where `dx, dy` are distances along axes. In your case something like:

```
dx = this.TargetX - this.StartX
```

Comment: Links to wikipedia (or more appropriate) would improve answer for future reading.